# Jquery grid,not working properly

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

am using the application in this link
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud2.php.I have added one more column say like 'empno' in the database by using phpmyadmin(using wamp server).And when i refresh the page..the newly added column is not displaying in the grid..And also the grid is small..I want to increase the height.How?

Thank you verymuch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

increase the height using this line :

```
 <table id="dg" title="My Users" style="width:550px;height:250px" //edit table height
```

and for the undisplayed column i don't know why this is happening recheck if the column is inserted in the table again in wamp server

Comment: @Ala..Thank you verymuch...Your code is worked.I need to change the HTML page to display the newly added column in the grid..Thank you again..